# abelian group such that every element has order $1$ or $p$ is vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose we have an abelian group $G$ such that every $g \in G$ has order either $1$ or $p$, where $p$ is a prime. I want to show that $G$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

My try:

suppose $\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $g \in G$, then

$ p \lambda g \cong_p 0 \implies \lambda g \in G $

Also, I have to show that product and sum of two elements in $G$ are in $G$. To show this, it is enough to show

$$ k g_2  \text{and} \; \; g_1 + g_2 $$

have order $p$ ?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: "product and sum of two elements" - do you gonsider two operations on $G$???

Comment: isnt a vector space supposed to be equipped with 2 operations?

Comment: The definition of a vector space does not suppose the existence of multiplication of vectors.

Comment: I meant scalar multiplication :z

Comment: But you write $g_1g_2$.

Comment: corrected now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\overline{k}\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ be the image of $k$. Define $\overline{k}g=kg$; this is correct since $kg=k'g$ for $k\equiv k'\mod p$. Then, e.g., $\overline{k}(g+h)=k(g+h)=kg+kh=\overline{k}g+\overline{k}h$, and similarly all other axioms of a vector space are verified.